# Import webpage via proxy server

Tags: import, url

I would like to import a webpage into Mathematica which is installed in a PC in the Intranet.  However, the webpage is blocked by the Intranet as it contains some forbidden words.

Is there any way to import such blocked webpage via Mathematica server or a proxy server to bypass the intranet?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adapting the proxy settings in the preferences panel

Comment: The usual way to do this would be to use a VPN. There are professional VPN services such as [Express VPN](https://www.expressvpn.com/). If you do that, then all your traffic (including the one from Mathematica) will be encrypted and impossible to read for any middleware.